# How to redirect a url that is incorrect to the correct page?

Tags: redirect

I am a beginner to programming. I accidentally sent out a piece of mail with the incorrect url to my site "www.website.com/location". The url should be "www.website.com/location.html". Is there a way to redirect to the correct page? I've done a bit of research for redirecting but it sounds like the incorrect page actually has to be a page. In my situation it is not. Is there a way to fix this?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! It is not easy to give a good answer to your question without any technical information about your system, e.g.: What kind of web server and web application are you using? Do you have full access to the web server configuration? You may want to update your question with that information to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities.
In the examples below I am using different page names, to avoid confusion with other objects named 'location'.
Suppose you sent out a message mentioning the wrong URL `http://www.example.com/mypage`, with the correct URL being `http://www.example.com/mypage.html`.

Configuration directives shown below are based on Apache web server, which is quite common for 'simple' web hosting.
Similar configuration settings exist on other web servers; ask your web host about the possibilities.

### URL rewriting

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to map `mypage` to `mypage.html`. Add the following section to `.htaccess` (add this file to your web folder if it does not exist yet).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mypage$ mypage.html
```

### JavaScript redirect

Next to the correct file `mypage.html`, put a second file named `mypage` (without extension `.html`) in the web folder, with the following contents:

```
<script>window.location='mypage.html';</script>
```

Whether this works, may depend on the configuration of the web server, in particular the MIME type mappings. I tried it on a standard Ubuntu Server configuration (Apache), and it worked.

### Folder

If the previous solution does not work, then there is this variation.
Instead of creating a file named `mypage`, create a *folder* with that name. In the folder, put a file named `index.html` with the following content:

```
<script>window.location='../mypage.html';</script>
```

Whether this works, depends on the configuration of [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html); if necessary, add/change `DirectoryIndex` and `DirectorySlash` directives in `.htaccess`.